# How to draw a family tree in Tableau with R?

Tags: r, tableau-api, rserve

I have a family tree which I can draw directly in R. However I'd like to load the source data in Tableau and use the package directly from within Tableau to display the family tree.

This is the data:

```
parent  child
erik    megan
erik    marina
erik    maureen
karin   megan
karin   marina
karin   maureen
erik    helena
erik    axel
erik    kim
erik    robin
karin   anna
karin   alfred
helena  jacobus
helena  maria
```

This is the R script that works fine (without Tableau):

```
library(GGally);
library(sna);
library(ggplot2);
library(network);
family <- read.table("c:/tmp/family_raw.txt", head=T);
ggnet2(family, label = TRUE);
```

The calculated field in Tableau however does not return the correct amount of data expected by Tableau:

```
SCRIPT_STR('
library(GGally);
library(sna);
library(ggplot2);
library(network);
data <- data.frame(parent=.arg1, child=.arg2);
nodes <- ggnet2(family)$data;
paste(nodes[,6],nodes[,7])
', ATTR([Parent]), ATTR([Child]))
```

Any advice?